# How do I install the web development workload into VS Professional?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I am following [instructions to create a web service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api) which mentions that I need the **ASP.NET and web development workload**.

I found mention of that [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/visual-studio-workloads/)  but not how to install it.

I found the [Visual Studio Professional 2017 component directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-professional) but it does not mention the **ASP.NET and web development workload**

I am running version 15.5.4

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/modify-visual-studio

Answer (score 3):

Run as administrator
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vs_installer.exe"

This is available from the start menu.